# Creating a dropdown item from another dropdown created within a callback function

Tags: callback, output, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

So I'm new to Dash, with experience in Shiny, and am having a bit of trouble configuring a dropdown menu. So I have 3 tabs in Dash and the behavior I currently have is the creation of a dropdown menu when a user clicks on the `medicaid` tab. I don't want this dropdown to appear for the other two tabs, hence why it is in my callback function. This dropdown (e.g. `state dropdown`) then gives the user a list of states.

My issue really lies in how to get the input value from the `state dropdown` since it is in the callback function...

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.read_csv("Timely and Effective Care - Hospital.csv", engine='python', sep=None)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    # tab selection menu dynamically created
    html.Div([
       dcc.Tabs(
           id='menu-tabs',
           value='tab-1',
           className='custom-tabs-container',
           children=[
               dcc.Tab(
                   label='Medicaid',
                   value='medicaid',
               ),
               dcc.Tab(
                   label='Commercial',
                   value='commercial',
               ),
               dcc.Tab(
                   label='Uninsured',
                   value='uninsured'
               ),
            ]),
    html.Div(id='state-dropdown'),
    html.Div(id='sample')
    ])

], className='wrapper')


@app.callback(Output('state-dropdown', 'children'),
               [Input('menu-tabs', 'value')])
def render_dropdown(tab):
    if tab == 'medicaid':
        return html.Div(children=[dcc.Dropdown(id='states',
                                  options=[{'label': i, 'value':i}
                                  for i in df['State'].unique()]
                        )])
```

What I want is another dropdown to be created within the `medicaid` tab...after a user selects a state from the first dropdown, the second dropdown should only list hospitals within the `state` selected from the first dropdown.

Hospital names are under the `hospital` column in `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dash does not like components being added after building the layout (ex. inside a callback), which makes this approach tough. I suggest looking at [this page](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/tabs) and following the tab "Content as Tab Children" approach. This will let you keep at least the basic form of the dropdowns in the layout (including the all-important IDs), and then use the callback to populate the values.

At that point, the callback should be much easier, because it only needs to update the `options` prop of the callback component which already exists.

Comment: Thanks! Coming from Shiny, I was thinking of the logic in a very limited way! This helped and I've been able to continue. Thanks a lot.